# Generate one point cloud from one mesh from one specific viewpoint

Tags: 3d, mesh, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

From one specific viewpoint, I hope to obtain corresponding point cloud from one mesh. 
`pcl_mesh2pcd` and `pcl_mesh_sampling` only convert one mesh to one point cloud and doesn't consider viewpoint problem. From one specific viewpoint, some port of the mesh will be invisible.
Maybe some function in the pcl library will perform such job. However I am not very familiar with each model in PCL and spend a lot of time for such function. Unfortunately I didn't find it.
I also search over the internet. Any help are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [simulation](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/tree/master/simulation) module of PCL.

Quote from [README_about_tools](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/simulation/tools/README_about_tools):

```
Test and Example Programs for pcl_simulation
mfallon and hordurj march 2012

1. sim_viewer.cpp
purpose: simulate in viewer which is almost the same as pcl_viewer
status : use the mouse to drive around, and 'v' to capture a cloud. reads vtk and obj. 
         visualizes vtk and makes pcd of obj. conflict between RL and VTK means doesn't visualize/simulate properly
was    : range_pcd_viewer.cpp

2. sim_terminal_demo.cpp
purpose: simple app to demo speed and api to pcl_simulation
status : reads obj, make a series of 640x480 simulated point clouds and exits
depndcy: OpenCV for writing png images

3. sim_test_performance.cpp
purpose: GLUT/GLEW viewer used by Hordur to test GLSL optimizations. Creates two different viewing planes
status : reads obj, creates window, use keyboard to drive around environment
was    : range_performance_test.cpp

4. sim_test_simple
purpose: similar code to #3 but has a 2x2 grid each containing 640x480 windows, but operates as #1. press 'v' to capture a cloud to file (only works properly if 2x2 canged to 1x1)
status : reads obj, creates window, use keyboard to drive around environment
was    : range_test_v2.cpp
```

`sim_viewer` is probably the tool you want to try out.

Comment: Thanks. I find virtaul_scanner is more appropriate. renderView from PCL visualization module can also do that.